# CSS3 fullscreen blur using GPU

Tags: css

I have a fullscreen background image that is blurred:

```
#bg {
    background: url('bg.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left:-120px;
    right:-120px;
    top:-120px;
    bottom:-120px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(60px);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This works fine, but I want like to hardware accelerate the blur, so I add:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This improves performance, but the blur loses the position offset, so the blur image no longer fills the entire screen. Is they any way to avoid this?

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/NLua6/1/

Comment: Did you try setting the width and height of #bg to 100%? Why do you have -120px for all of the position properties? A live demo would make helping you with this much easier

Comment: updated with jsFiddle, height 100% does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `height` style and changed all `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` styles to `0`.

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7PLZM/)***

## ***CSS***

---

```
#bg {
    background-image:url('http://www.whitegadget.com/attachments/pc-wallpapers/16950d1224057972-landscape-wallpaper-blue-river-scenery-wallpapers.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    -webkit-filter: blur(60px);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);   
}
```

## ***Output***

---

[image]

Comment: This just shows the problem - you can see the red background around the edges of the blur.