# CSS fullscreen blur using GPU

Tags: css, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I have exactly the problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908052/css3-fullscreen-blur-using-gpu) question but I can't comment (as I have less than 50rep).

It has to do with getting a better performance out of blurring a full screen image through GPU acceleration but not having the sides "leaking".

Comment: Want to minus this ... but can't find it in my heart just because of your sheer resolve to will an answer for that question and person. Welldone give it a while there will be more questions and you will soon up your rep.

Comment: thx for not minusing it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding an additional `div`, you can add a wrapper and apply the transformation to it. 
I checked in Chrome Dev Tools and indeed Chrome rendered the wrapper `#bg` into a separate layer, although this kind of optimizations are very browser specific.
I would recommend reading https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/

I would give you another suggestion however, instead using a big image and blur it, you can use the same image at a very low resolution (say 10x10 px) and make it full-screen. Almost the same result, but with far lesser bytes to load.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#bg > div {
    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920/');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    top: -60px;
    right: -60px;
    bottom: -60px;
    filter: blur(60px);
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div></div>
</div>
```